# List.Sort() fails when the list has null values

Tags: c#

I have a user control in that a grid gets data using ObjectDataSource. All the columns in the grid are sortable. If the user clicks on a particular column name, the list is sorted based on that column (List.Sort(sortColumn)).

I am facing an issue when one of the column has blank / null value in their field. The comparison line strA.CompareTo(strB) fails with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when strA/ strB is null or both are null.

How ever, I have included !string.IsNullOrEmpty() for strA and strB to avoid the null refernce exception. Still it doesn't sort the grid.

The code snippet is given below.

```
int IComparer<MyWorklistItem>.Compare(MyWorkItem x, MyWorkItem y)
{
        int sortValue = 1;
        if (this.strSortField.Length == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        MyWorkItem item1 = this.blnSortDesc ? y : x;
        MyWorkItem item2 = this.blnSortDesc ? x : y;

        PropertyInfo property1 = item1.GetType().GetProperty(this.strSortField);
        PropertyInfo property2 = item2.GetType().GetProperty(this.strSortField);

        string strA = (string)property1.GetValue(item1, null);
        string strB = (string)property2.GetValue(item2, null);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strA) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(strB))
        {               
            sortValue = strA.CompareTo(strB);
        }           
        return sortValue;
    }
```

How do I sort, when one of the values or both are null.

**Note: I am using VS 2005, so no possibility for LINQ though.**

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but you only need to declare one PropertyInfo object, since both items are the same class.  You can use that one PropertyInfo object to call .GetValue on both items.  Since reflection is a little more "expensive" for the processor, this will be a minor performance improvement.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the static `string.Compare` method rather than the instance method to avoid problems with null, given that you are always comparing string properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `GetType` on the variables before doing the null check.

If you do a null check before anything else that should take care of everything.

Comment: Although that is why it can't handle nulls, the OP is also asking how to handle them when sorting. If you don't return something, your "sorted list" will be randomly interspersed with null values.

Comment: I look at that as "how do I make it not crash" rather than, "which should go first".  Either way, you've already covered it, so why redundantly provide the same information.

Comment: I believe the OP was more concerned about the fields within the object being null, but I do agree the objects themselves should be checked for null as well.

Comment: Servy, I took your point into consideration and implemented Adam's solution as well. Thanks for your input !

Comment: @MCattle It's clear that OP is concerned with properties being null, which is exactly what could be tripping him up.  He's checked them for null, but not `x` and `y`.  Since he didn't give a stack trace for the error we don't know which cause the exception.